# How to execute a stored procedure in kotlin

Tags: sql-server, kotlin, jtds, datagrip

I would like to run the `master.sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring` sql procedure in kotlin. If I run that procedure in Datagrip it looks like this:

```
begin
declare @fsetprefix bit = null
declare @pbinin varbinary(max) = null
declare @startoffset int = 0
declare @cbytesin int = 0
declare @result nvarchar(max)
exec
    @result = sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring
        @fsetprefix,
        @pbinin,
        @startoffset,
        @cbytesin
select @result as result
end
```

The only thing I would like to change is `@pbinin` with the value `HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONVERT(varchar(255), ?)+'DEL'+?)`. The value of the first questionmark is the password in clear text, the second one is the salt.That works fine. But how do I call that procedure in kotlin? I tried this

```
val pStmt = con?.prepareCall("\\{call master.sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0,HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONVERT" + "(varchar(255), ${user.clearPassword})+'DEL'+${user.salt}),1,0)\\}")
    pStmt?.registerOutParameter("result", Types.VARCHAR)
    val cursor = pStmt?.executeQuery()
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.next()) {
            val result = cursor.getString("result")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why the \s at the beginning and end? But you really shouldn't have to call out to the database for this: this is an operation you can easily implement in Kotlin itself.

Comment: Actually, that's not even a stored procedure: it's a function. You can just `SELECT` it, and use whatever JTDS's version of executeScalar is to run it. But I'll say it again: you should not be making a database call for this. Use Java's or Kotlin's built-in SHA1, or find a library that'll do something like scrypt for you instead.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is just an example for me how to call that function